Is there a way to access APL+Win's ability to generate an expression for a value?
When hovering the mouse over a variable name in APL+Win, a value tip is shown, with (the beginning of) an expression that would evaluate to the variable's value. How do I access this ability programmatically, so I can get an expression for any given value?


Is there someway to populate a tool tip via APL? This feels like you want to fill the tool tip with the (potentially modified) ouput of ]REPR myVar

@Silas Sorry, I don't follow. I am asking for something similar to ]REPR but for APL+Win, not Dyalog.

Ah, sorry - I read your question as attempting to generate an equivalent, not simply requiring assistance with APL+Win
